# Using jquery to remove Parsley Excluded doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I have a task which required me to selectively validate an input using parsley, then exclude it from parsley once a valid value is entered (make it read only). BUT if the user clears it out, I need to remove the excluded data attribute, and re-bind parsley to the form. I'm doing all of this, but it's as if either a. excluded isn't actually removed, or b. parsley isn't re-bound. Here's some code:

```
var handleValidation = function($form, type){
            //this works for the initial validation. Meaning it will return
            //false the first time (before I add/remove the excluded data attr)
            var formId =  $form.attr('id');
            var valid = $('#' + formId).parsley().validate({group: ""+type + "-validation", force: true});
            return valid;
};

var reBindParsley = function(parsleyDef,formId){
        $('#' + formId).parsley().destroy();
        parsleyDef();
    };

    $clearIcon.click(function(){
        //find input traversing the dom
        $input.prop("readonly", false); //this works fine
        $input.removeData('parsley-excluded'); //not sure if this is needed
        $input.removeAttr('data-parsley-excluded'); //this gets removed from the visual representation of the DOM, 
                                                 //but when i call validation on it, it's as if it's still there
        reBindParsley();
    })

//this will handle validating the input
$myInput.click(function(){
    var valid = handleValidation($form, type);
    if(valid){
        makeReadOnly() //adds $myInput.attr('data-parsley-excluded', true);
        reBindParsley(parsleyFunction, form);
    }
});
```

So after calling the code in the clearIcon click event, the nexst time i click the input, it should call handleValidation(), and return false if the value isn't valid (like it does the FIRST time), but doesn't. I checked the visual representation of the DOM in firefox debugger, and the excluded data isn't there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you happen to have a jsfiddle that we can use to reproduce this issue and debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% what's going on, but there is a simpler way.

`$input.removeData('parsley-excluded')` is not needed, nor is calling `destroy`.

`var formId =  $form.attr('id'); var valid = $('#' + formId).parsley...` is simply `$form.parsley...`

Simply add to the form's excluded list `[readonly]` and you should be pretty much good to go. Otherwise, please post a working fiddle.

Comment: Wow that is a much more elegant solution, thank you! Can't believe I didn't think of that